# Change color off an id on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

So I wanted to do this: [Change CSS After Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392145/change-css-after-scrolling/28392180)
But to change color instead of opacity. Changing opacity had no problem at all, while changing color wont work.

Here's a working example of changing the opacity:

```
function changeCss () {
    var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
    var navElement = document.querySelector("#föremåll");
    this.scrollY > 500 ? navElement.style.opacity = .8 : navElement.style.opacity = 1;
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss , false);
```

And here's a example of what I tried to do (changing color):

```
  function changeCss () {
      var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
      var navElement = document.querySelector("#föremåll");
      this.scrollY > 500 ? navElement.style.color = "#000000" : navElement.style.color = "#4a4646";
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss , false);
```

But it doesn't seem to work... I also don't understand the

```
: navElement.style.opacity = 1;
```

part. Is it like "else"?

Anyway, thanks in advance. I hope that you can help me so that I can change the color while scrolling. (I'm new to programming & stack overflow).

Comment: Are you trying to change the font color, or background color? Because `style.color` is font color. The `condition? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse` is called the [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and it is indeed similar to if-else.

Comment: I'm trying to change a list items font color yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question about `: navElement.style.opacity = 1;`

In this code,

```
this.scrollY > 500 ? navElement.style.color = "#000000" : navElement.style.color = "#4a4646";
```

you are seeing a if-else block. The format is as follows:

Condition `?` If true `:` If false.

```js
function changeCss() {
  var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
  var navElement = document.querySelector("#föremåll a");
  this.scrollY > 500 ? navElement.style.color = "#629f46" : navElement.style.color = "#b95252";
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss, false);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100em;
}
#föremåll {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<li id="föremåll"><b><a href="#Föremål">Föremål</a></b></li>
```

In your code, you were selecting the parent li. You need to add `a` to your querySelector to get the anchor tag and change its color. Try to use variable names that do not have special characters in them.

Comment: Alright, I see. Do you know though why changing the color doesnt work? I'm trying to change a ul li font color

Comment: @Benjamin Sure let me pull an example together.

Comment: @Benjamin updated answer. Does this help?

Comment: `<li id="föremåll"><b><a href="#Föremål">Föremål</a></b></li>`

Comment: Trying to change "Föremål" font color. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Benjamin Updated answer. You were selecting the `li` and not the `a`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233189/discussion-between-benjamin-and-jeff-b).