# How to display the box-shadow on scrolling down a few pixels?

Tags: html, css, header

Here's the topnav CSS code:

```
.topnav{
                background-color: #d9d9d9;
                position:fixed;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px -8px #d9d9d9;
            }
```

html code:

```
<div class="topnav">
<a href="index.html" class="active" >Home</a>
<a href="explore.html">Explore</a>
</div>
```

I want the box shadow to appear on scrolling down a few pixels, then disappear on scrolling back to top.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with just CSS. You'll need to use JavaScript to detect when you have scrolled down the page and apply a modifier class to your `topnav` element.

Comment: You will have to use JS for this to work. The [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) listens to scroll and you can add and remove a css class to/from the navbar depending on the value of `window.scroll`

Comment: IntersectionObserver can be useful here - saves having to listen for all scroll events.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO is not a code writing service. You should try to solve the problem yourself using the hints given to you. If you get stuck, feel free to ask a new question. You can also search for similar questions here. Maybe someone has already had the same question, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392145/change-css-after-scrolling/28392180